# xargs and sed creating unwanted files when replacing strings in files

Tags: bash, unix, sed, xargs

I have a folder named `test` which has two files `style.css` and a hidden file named `.DS_Store`. My aim is to recursively replace all "changefrom.this" strings in all files under `test` to "to.this". So I came up with:

```
folder_root="test"

# change text in files
find $folder_root/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/changefrom.this/to.this/g'
```

And while the strings do get replaced in the `style.css` file for instance, the execution outputs an error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

And I get some new files in the `test` folder: `style.css-e` and `!2766!.DS_Store`. Didn't expect that. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this simplified command with `find -exec sed`:

```
find "$folder_root/" -type f -exec sed -i 's/changefrom\.this/to.this/g' '{}' +
```

If `changefrom.this` is not the actual pattern you're using then let us know what that pattern is as it might be causing problems.

Comment: i want the exact string `changefrom.this` to be replaced. The dot is there because it's a part of the string. It shouldn't indicate anything else

Comment: You can use: `sed -i 's/\<changefrom\.this\>/to.this/g'` for exact match. dot needs to be replaced to match literal dot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find $folder_root/ -type f -print0 | LC_ALL=en_US.CP437 xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e 's/changefrom.this/to.this/g'
```

If it works, the problem is your terminal encoding doesn't match the file's encoding. CP437 doesn't have bad bytes so this fixes it for regexes in 7 bit ascii.

Comment: Now there is no error, the string was replaced but two new files were created: `style.css-e` and `.DS_Store-e`

Comment: The reason you're getting new files created is because '-i' takes a file extension to save backup files with (the '-e'). The '-e' is probably meant to be '-E' (extended regex) and you need to pass a zero-length extension to sed to tell it not to save a backup.